# I could not save the file in developer console

Tags: developer-console

Every time I save the file in developer console the "Save As" window will display which will save as a webpage instead of save the file itself.
[image: issue on saving file]

Comment: Also mention your web browser in question.

Comment: This issue is for all browsers

Comment: Not sure why this is happening. But are you sure your control/cursor is at the text area of the file you are trying to save?

Comment: I just tried in Chrome  57.0.2987.133 and Edge 38.14393.0.0. Both had `CTRL+S` bound to the save operation rather than the native browsers web page save action. What happens if you use the menus to save the page?

Comment: if I try to save via menu the file won't save.